# What's the most efficient way of handling transactions with multiple signers

Tags: transactions

I'm building a program where the most of the transactions are signed by two different users. In order to boost UX and effectively sign transactions by two parties, what methods can I use?

Comment: I'd rather recommend to have one signer only and set it as a multisig.
I'd personally recommend to try this dapp - https://v3.squads.so